# Subtlety in conversion of characters to integers

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Can someone explain clearly what these lines from K&R actually mean:

> "**When a char is converted to an int, can it ever produce a negative
>   integer?** The answer varies from machine to machine. The definition of
>   C guarantees that any character in the *machine's standard printing
>   character set will never be negative*, but arbitrary bit patterns
>   stored in character variables may appear to be negative on some
>   machines,yet positive on others".

Comment: Whether the type `char` is equivalent to the type `signed char` or the type `unsigned char` is implementation defined.

Comment: Can you please explain the line, "The definition of C guarantees..."?

Comment: At the time this historical work was written, was probably referring to the ASCII character set which has values 0..127 and so cannot be negative with an 8-bit char.

Comment: "The definition of C guarantees" can reasonably be interpreted as "The C language specifications require".  K&R probably had a slightly different meaning in mind, but that's tied up with their particular language implementations and the architectures of the machines on which those ran.

Comment: You'd have to know what a "standard printing character set" should mean ... this is outdated and probably they were thinking about ASCII, maybe EBCDIC ... `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`, so given this statement, `char` can only be signed by default if the "standard printing character set" uses only 7 bits, as ASCII does.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Or if `CHAR_BIT` is greater than eight...

Comment: Thanks, and one more thing, is there any significance of the value printed if I try convert a multi-character constant to int. Like in this code,#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int c='17';
 printf("%d",c);
 return 0;
}  Output:12599. Please explain, I am a beginner in C.

Comment: Multi-character constants have an implementation-defined value.  The only significance of the value is that's how that compiler on that machine interprets the multi-character constant.  The standard says (§6.4.4.4 Character constants, ¶10): _The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
`'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
execution character, is implementation-defined._

Comment: Note: in comments, use backticks around code to present it as code: `#include<stdio.h> int main() { int c='17'; printf("%d",c); return 0; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand several things first.

1. If I take an 8-bit value and extend it to a 16-bit value, normally you would imagine just adding a bunch of 0's on the left.  For example, if I have the 8-bit value 23, in binary that's 00010111, so as a 16-bit number it's 0000000000010111, which is also 23.
2. It turns out that negative numbers always have a 1 in the high-order bit.  (There might be weird machines for which this is not true, but it's true for any machine you're likely to use.)  For example, the 8-bit value -40 is represented in binary as 11011000.
3. So when you convert a signed 8-bit value to a 16-bit value, if the high-order bit is 1 (that is, if the number is negative), you do not add a bunch of 0-s on the left, you add a bunch of 1's instead.  For example, going back to -40, we would convert 11011000 to 1111111111011000, which is the 16-bit representation of -40.
4. There are also unsigned numbers, that are never negative.  For example, the 8-bit unsigned number 216 is represented as 11011000.  (You will notice that this is the same bit pattern as the signed number -40 had.)  When you convert an unsigned 8-bit number to 16 bits, you add a bunch of 0's no matter what.  For example, you would convert 11011000 to 0000000011011000, which is the 16-bit representation of 216.
5. So, putting this all together, if you're converting an 8-bit number to 16 (or more) bits, you have to look at two things.  First, is the number signed or unsigned?  If it's unsigned, just add a bunch of 0's on the left.  But if it's signed, you have to look at the high-order bit of the 8-0bit number.  If it's 0 (if the number is positive), add a bunch of 0's on the left.  But if it's 1 (if the number is negative), add a bunch of 1's on the right.  (This whole process is known as *sign extension*.)
6. The ordinary ASCII characters (like 'A' and '1' and '$') all have values less than 128, which means that their high-order bit is always 0.  But "special" characters from the "Latin-1" or UTF-8 character sets have values greater than 128.  For this reason they're sometimes also called "high bit" or "eighth bit" characters.  For example, the Latin-1 character Ø (O with a slash through it it) has the value 216.
7. Finally, although type `char` in C is typically an 8-bit type, *the C Standard does not specify whether it is signed or unsigned*.

Putting this all together, what Kernighan and Ritchie are saying is that when we convert a `char` to a 16- or 32-bit integer, we don't quite know how to apply step 5.  If I'm on a machine where type `char` is unsigned, and I take the character Ø and convert it to an int, I'll probably get the value 216.  But if I'm on a machine where type `char` is signed, I'll probably get the number -40.

Comment: Great answer, and this makes me ponder over a point. If I'm on a machine where type char is signed, then we get -40, which is 1111111111011000. Can it be considered one reason that int is by default signed in C. Since this number should represent -40, but if int had been unsigned by default, we would have great ambiguity as this binary representation could also represent 65496, which is not what we should get. Or am I just being naive?

Comment: @Duncan I wouldn't say that.  Ints are signed by default because that's what's generally useful.  If ints were unsigned by default, chars would probably be unsigned by default, too, and you'd get what you wanted (216 would go to 216).  If ints were unsigned but chars were signed, I'm not 100% sure what would happen, but it would probably be surprising and counterintuitive at least some of the time.

Answer (score 1):

There are two more-or-less relevant parts to the standard — ISO/IEC 9899:2011.

> #### 6.2.5 Types
>
> ¶3 An object declared as type `char` is large enough to store any member of the basic
>   execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a
>   `char` object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative. If any other character is stored in
>   a `char` object, the resulting value is implementation-defined but shall be within the range
>   of values that can be represented in that type.
>
> ¶15 The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called
>   the *character types*. The implementation shall define `char` to have the same range,
>   representation, and behavior as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.<sup>45)</sup>
>
> <sup>45)</sup> `CHAR_MIN`, defined in `<limits.h>`, will have one of the values `0` or `SCHAR_MIN`, and this can be
>   used to distinguish the two options. Irrespective of the choice made, `char` is a separate type from the
>   other two and is not compatible with either.

That defines what your quote from K&R states.  The other relevant part defines what the basic execution character set is.

> #### 5.2.1 Character sets
>
> ¶1 Two sets of characters and their associated collating sequences shall be defined: the set in
>   which source files are written (the *source character set*), and the set interpreted in the
>   execution environment (the *execution character set*). Each set is further divided into a
>   *basic character set*, whose contents are given by this subclause, and a set of zero or more
>   locale-specific members (which are not members of the basic character set) called
>   *extended characters*. The combined set is also called the extended character set. The
>   values of the members of the execution character set are implementation-defined.
>
> ¶2 In a character constant or string literal, members of the execution character set shall be
>   represented by corresponding members of the source character set or by *escape
>   sequences* consisting of the backslash `\` followed by one or more characters. A byte with
>   all bits set to 0, called the *null character*, shall exist in the basic execution character set; it
>   is used to terminate a character string.
>
> ¶3 Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following
>   members: the 26 *uppercase letters* of the Latin alphabet
>
> ```
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M
> N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> ```
>
> the 26 *lowercase letters* of the Latin alphabet
>
> ```
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m
> n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> ```
>
> the 10 decimal *digits*
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> ```
>
> the following 29 graphic characters
>
> ```
> ! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - . / :
> ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
> ```
>
> the space character, and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and
>   form feed. The representation of each member of the source and execution basic
>   character sets shall fit in a byte. In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
>   value of each character after `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
>   the value of the previous. In source files, there shall be some way of indicating the end of
>   each line of text; this International Standard treats such an end-of-line indicator as if it
>   were a single new-line character. In the basic execution character set, there shall be
>   control characters representing alert, backspace, carriage return, and new line. If any
>   other characters are encountered in a source file (except in an identifier, a character
>   constant, a string literal, a header name, a comment, or a preprocessing token that is never
>   converted to a token), the behavior is undefined.
>
> ¶4 A *letter* is an uppercase letter or a lowercase letter as defined above; in this International
>   Standard the term does not include other characters that are letters in other alphabets.
>
> ¶5 The universal character name construct provides a way to name other characters.

One consequence of these rules is that if a machine uses 8-bit character and [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) encoding, then plain `char` must be an unsigned type since the digits have code 240..249 in EBCDIC.