# Plain characters in C language

Tags: c, char

The following statement is from Dennis Ritchie C book

> The qualifier signed or unsigned may be applied to char or any integer. unsigned
>   numbers are always positive or zero, and obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2n, where n is the
>   number of bits in the type. So, for instance, if chars are 8 bits, unsigned char variables
>   have values between 0 and 255, while signed chars have values between -128 and 127 (in a
>   two's complement machine.) **Whether plain chars are signed or unsigned is machine-dependent**,
>   but printable characters are always positive.

From [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isprint.htm) i got the definition "**A printable character is a character that is not a control character**". The C library function `int isprint(int c)` checks whether the passed character is printable.

I did not able to find what are plain chars in C. Where can I find the list of plain chars in c?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077321/subtlety-in-conversion-of-characters-to-integers .

Comment: Beware that `isprint` expects an _unsigned_ char and may fail for plain characters, which are often signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's referring to `char` type (as opposed to `unsigned char` or `signed char`).